# VBA Macro in Excel for hiding all worksheets that are not selected

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using the following VBA macro code below to hide all but the active worksheet:

```
    Sub HideWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Are there any options to extend it so that it will  hide all but the selected worksheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the **Windows(#).SelectedSheets**. One way is to hide all except ActiveSheet, then unhide those Selected.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Hide all except activeone
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next
    ' Unhide selected worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```